# Расчитать начальные координаты пули

Tags: java, c++, разработка-игр, box2d, формулы

Пишу 2d игру с видом сверху. Как рассчитать начальные координаты пули, которая должна быть на конце ствола? Т.к. использую box2d игрок имеет форму круга, изначально использовал такую формулу: 

`pos` - позиция, `raduis` - радиус тела игрока, `rot` - поворот (уже известен) 

`pos.x + radius * Math.cos(rot)`

`pos.y + radius * Math.sin(rot)`
Но пули появлялись в плотную от игрока и происходила коллизиция, т.е. игрок попадал сам в себя. Как сделать, что бы пуля появлялась "на конце ствола" и был правильный вылет. Можете ответить на любом языке, мне только формула нужна.

Comment: не проще ли проверять коллизию, и если это игрок - то ничего не делать?  или как сложный-хак - отключать коллизию с игроком на момент выстрела?

Comment: а то усадить пулю на 0,0023мм выше - ну это смешно же))

Comment: У пули тоже есть на маленький радиус + из-за этого будет кривая стрельба. Я уже сам перепробывал 1000 и 1 костыль, так что подобные "лайфкахи не стоит писать"

Comment: ну естесственно лучше сделать формулу длиной в поезд, чтобы рассчитывала одну миллионную миллиметра отклонения от персонажа :D

Comment: радиус снаряда может достигать 8 единиц, в то время как у самого персонажа радиус 20, отклонение будет большое

Comment: А просто увеличить радиус не пойдёт? и какой-нибудь глупой ошибки вроде вычисления в целых числах нет?

Comment: Увеличить радиус чего? и как это должно помочь? Ошибок нет, хоть и половины пули создаются внутри игрока, она от него отталкивается из-за особенности работы box2d. Как раз из-за этого и получается коллизия

Comment: радиус в формуле/"радиус ствола"

Comment: В box2d из коробки есть поддержка 16 групп для определения столкновений. Используйте фильтрацию столкновений путем распределения игрока и пуль по разным группам.

Comment: Самый простой вариант - сделать в формулах прибавку к радиусу, чтобы пуля создавалась чуть дальше от персонажа.

Comment: @VTT, вы про фильтры, какие-то стандартные методы или что? можно, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее

Comment: Добавить к радиусу игрока в формулу ещё и радиус пули, не?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если представить игрока в виде окружности и ствол в виде касательной к окружности, то выйдет подобный рисунок:

[image: Изображение]

Вам нужно найти позицию пули, зная позицию, радиус и поворот персонажа? Пожалуйста:

1. Рассчитываем позицию конца ствола в локальных координатах объекта и без поворота. Это будет: `x = R` и `y = L`, где `R` - радиус вашего персонажа, а `L` - длина ствола.
2. Вращаем точку ствола:

   ```
   x = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)
   y = x * sin(angle) + y * cos(angle)
   ```

   Где `x` и `y` - значения предыдущего шага, `angle` - угол, на который повернут персонаж.
3. Добавляем к `x` и `y` позицию персонажа в мире, тем самым "перемещая" точку конца ствола из локального пространства персонажа в мировое - `x = x + pos.x`, `y = y + pos.y`

Ну и потом создаем пулю в полученной точке, добавляем ей импульс в направлении взгляда персонажа...

Если же направление взгляда персонажа нужно найти, то выгоднее по производительности сделать так:

```
    dirX = -sin(angle) // x-компонента вектора взгляда
    dirY = cos(angle) // y-компонента вектора взгляда

    x = pos.x + R * cos(angle) + dirX * L
    y = pos.y + R * sin(angle) + dirY * L
```

Т.е. те же действия, что вы и делали, + добавляем вектор взгляда, умноженный на длину ствола. Прошу заметить, что `-sin(angle) = cos(angle + PI / 2)`, так что минус там не случайно.

UPD: откуда я взял формулу для поворота - [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Поворот](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82)

Comment: то что надо! спасибо большое, важно было найти способ с помощью координат, т.к. я хотел с помощью этого добавить всякие фитчи, например эффекты. Работает отлично

Answer (score 2):

В box2D есть встроенная поддержка фильтрации столкновений. Фильтрация имеет две ступени

- разделение на группы: объекты, принадлежащие разным группам не сталкиваются; следует использовать, когда объекты полностью независимы;
- разделение внутри группы по 16-битной маске: каждому объекту присваивается маска категории, к которой он принадлежит (обычно 1 бит), и маска категории объектов, с которыми он должен сталкиваться; следует использовать, когда объекты не должны сталкиваться между собой, но могут сталкиваться с некоторым третьим объектом.

Ваша ситуация скорее подпадает под 2 категорию - пули и игрок не должны сталкиваться между собой однако и пули, и игрок должны сталкиваться со стенками.

Задавать эти параметры можно при создании fixture, например:

```
int16 const main_group_id{1};
uint16 const flag_wall{0x0001};
uint16 const flag_player{0x0002};
uint16 const flag_bullet{0x0004};

b2FixtureDef wall_fixture_def;
wall_fixture_def.filter.categoryBits = flag_wall; // что такое
wall_fixture_def.filter.maskBits = flag_player | flag_bullet; // с кем сталкиваться
wall_fixture_def.filter.groupIndex = main_group_id;
b2Fixture * p_wall_fixture = p_wall_body->CreateFixture(&wall_fixture_def);

b2FixtureDef player_fixture_def;
player_fixture_def.filter.categoryBits = flag_player; // что такое
player_fixture_def.filter.maskBits = flag_wall; // с кем сталкиваться
player_fixture_def.filter.groupIndex = main_group_id;
// create player fixtures...

b2FixtureDef bullet_fixture_def;
bullet_fixture_def.filter.categoryBits = flag_bullet; // что такое
bullet_fixture_def.filter.maskBits = flag_wall; // с кем сталкиваться
bullet_fixture_def.filter.groupIndex = main_group_id;
// create bullet fixtures...
```

Или позже посредством метода `b2Fixture::SetFilterData`.

Comment: 1 вариант точно не подходит
2 вариант - вы представляете, что у пули нет коллизии с персонажом? Достаточно глупо. В моем случае подходит только вариант изменять группу колизий сразу после выстрела. Я так и сделал (временно) и хотя даже поставил возвращение пули в общую группу сразу после того как она начала двигаться (т.е. вот пуля создалась, ей задали скорость, она пролетела какой-то участок вперед, чтоб не удариться с игроком и сразу же вернулася в общую группу), из-за огромной скорости она успевает пролететь приличное расстояние и если подойти вплотную к стене, пули проходят сковзь стену

Comment: @UlaLa А зачем пуле коллизии с персонажем? Персонаж играет в русскую рулетку или это пуля-бумеранг? Если пуля может попасть в персонажа отскакивая от стен, то фильтр можно менять при ударе об стену. Чтобы она не проходила сквозь стену следует все же фильтровать по маске.